# Saving NSManagedObject via MagicalRecord does not work

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, magicalrecord

I have create an object:

```
let exercise = ExerciseEntity.mr_createEntity()

func updateLocalExercise(with exercise: ExerciseEntity, completion: @escaping (ResultInfo<[ExerciseEntity]>) -> Void) {

                MagicalRecord.save({ (context) in

if let localExercise = exercise.mr_(context) { this actually nil and throws some error in log
}

}
```

My question is how to save ExerciseEntity.mr_createEntity correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait` to save data. Check all save methods in `NSManagedObjectContext (MagicalSaves)` class.

You should use `MR_createEntityInContext` instead of `MR_createEntity`. `MR_createEntity` is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code to store entity.

```
let compltedTaskModel : CompletedTaskModel = CompletedTaskModel.mr_createEntity()!
 compltedTaskModel.title = taskList.title
 compltedTaskModel.description_text = taskList.description_text
 compltedTaskModel.workflow_description = taskList.workflow_description
 compltedTaskModel.last_updated = taskList.last_updated
 compltedTaskModel.respondent_pk = taskList.respondent_pk
 compltedTaskModel.isFlag = taskList.isFlag
 NSManagedObjectContext.mr_default().mr_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait()
```

Do not forgot to add below line in AppDelegate file.

```
MagicalRecord.setupAutoMigratingCoreDataStack()
```

See [this raywenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/1696-getting-started-with-magicalrecord) blog for full demo code with steps.
Do let me know if you want more information.

Comment: @Matrosov Alexander I hope this answer works for you. If you required more help then let me know. Thanks